Can the Garbage Collector move a struct during a call?
I'm implementing a stack based vector type like this:
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct VectorI16x8 {
        public short s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7;
        public short this[int i] {
            get => UnsafeValues[i];
            set => UnsafeValues[i] = value;
        }
        public int Length => 8;
        private Span<short> UnsafeValues => MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref s0, Length);
    }

It's pretty clear that if I made UnsafeValues public, it would be possible for values of this struct to be moved in memory (even without the garbage collector), leading to a dangling reference within the Span or causing the Span to point to an incorrect instance.
However, what is less clear is whether using a span like this privately within my struct implementation is safe. My question is: can I assume that my struct's this will not move during the execution of my indexer (meaning that the span created by UnsafeValues will remain valid) or would I have to use a fixed block to make this safe?

Method remarks mention this: This method can be useful if part of a managed object represents a fixed array.

tangential: you might want to look at "inline arrays" - consider: [InlineArray(8)] public struct VectorI16x8 { private short _element0; } - https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABADAAgwRgDoAlAVwDsAXASwFsZCBhCWgB2oBsYoBlbgN2pgYAZwDcAWABQ0/gEMoOCMABWOALw5yMAO44AajDCVoASXxIEADgAUASklSA9E6WqA2gE4AuhpwAmMRwXHG4oaBwAQQAVHEYAeQBZAAVTABkAURxo00SMgEJpaWoqHGo/AHEYSgA5Eph7R2UVd2pfTUCimSkCJDLSqtr6+w0APhxPR2l3U3IOesioKDkATxsrO29pDABmHBFKKFJjAyMTKHNLKxwAbxxWKGp5Shh9gAtoShwAfRgueioWCCAF8gA

@MarcGravell I'm aware of inline arrays but can't use anything newer than .NET Standard 2.1 in Unity. Also I do kind of want to expose all of the values as named fields in addition to making them indexable.

@Sinatr I believe that is referring to the struct representing a fixed-size array, which it is. But that doesn't tell me about pinning requirements for using the struct overall, and there is a pretty big warning message about how the lifetime of the returned span will not be properly tracked even in span aware languages.

there are no pinning requirements - that's the entire point of using managed pointers; of course, this assumes that Unity gets all of this logic right ;p

You do not require a fixed block for this; the short version is that the GC is required to handle this scenario. Spans are fundamentally no different to any other "interior pointer" - and the same problem could be initiated by some method in your struct invoking DoSomething(ref s0), DoSomethingElse(in s1), etc. This is part of why managed pointers (ref, Span<T>, etc) can only be stored on the stack, not as fields on types (except for ref struct) - so that the GC knows where to check for them (it needs to walk the stackframes anyay, to check for fixed markers, etc - which are just special tokens on locals). Whether the GC handles this by deciding not to move those regions (as though they were fixed), or to fixup the references (during a pause) is an implementation detail of the GC.
(minor note: depending on the runtime, there is a 3-field span or a 2-field span; they are engineered differently depending on the capabilities of the runtime to handle this scenario, but either way the short version is "magic happens" and it works without you needing to panic)

Glad you responded instead of someone giving a random "value types are on stack and not processed by the GC" nonsense that ignores common scenarios like structs as a member of a class.

This does do something you can't do with a regular ref though: structs are not allowed to return references to themselves or their fields, but that's effectively what UnsafeValues is doing, so I wonder if that makes a difference? It seems this would definitely be safe if I inlined the call to MemoryMarshal though.

@zstewart yep, there might be some problems along those grounds - and indeed the ref in CreateSpan is declared scoped, so you would hope the compiler gets fussy here; if there is an issue there, however: it doesn't relate to fixed vs not - and is more likely to relate to a ref escaping declaration and corrupting stack space by using the same chunk for incompatible purposes at the same time. I'm unable to make it fail locally, however.

Further: consider - the fields could be public, in which case the caller can obtain a ref to the fields. Different flavor of the same problem.

My takeaway then is that although the compiler won't prevent me from making a dangling reference with MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan, as long as the reference is still to live memory, the GC won't break it.

Important: the code you show is fine from a purely GC perspective; as I said previously: the GC is required to handle these pointers.
But: that doesn't make it safe! This usage of CreateSpan is not safe, and can lead to unexpected / incorrect outcomes, as demonstrated by the following example:
(it isn't obvious, but the problem here comes from passing the value as a parameter, with the property accessor becoming a ldarga on the parameter, which is in the ambient argument stack space which is logically undefined /reusable after the termination of InnocentLookingMethod)
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

var a = InnocentLookingMethod(new SomeStruct(10));
Console.WriteLine($"a: {a[0]}");

var b = InnocentLookingMethod(new SomeStruct(42));
Console.WriteLine($"b: {b[0]}");

var delta = Unsafe.ByteOffset<int>(in a[0], in b[0]);
if (delta == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("oops! we have the same location twice!");
    Console.WriteLine($"a: {a[0]}, b: {b[0]}");
}

static Span<int> InnocentLookingMethod(SomeStruct foo) => foo.Span;

struct SomeStruct
{
    public SomeStruct(int i) => this.i = i;
    int i;
    public Span<int> Span => MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref i, 1);
}

Ideally this should be handled by something similar to CS8347, CS8166, CS8170 or one of the rules that enforces scoped logic, but: it is not detected in this case, which can lead to very confusing outcomes.
Note that this gap seems to be specific to MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan; if you use new Span<SomeType>(ref field), CS8170 is triggered. Other scenarios tend to trigger either CS8170 or CS8347. MemoryMarshal is akin to Unsafe, in that it is explicitly saying "I know what I'm doing", when perhaps in this case: it isn't so obvious!
Interestingly using an inline-array in this way triggers CS8166, unless the inline-array is itself passed by-ref (which makes sense).
In more extreme scenarios, I guess this could also lead to accidentally creating a scenario where you have the capability to overwrite a ref-type managed pointer (the pointer itself, not the dereferenced location) with garbage (via a dangling pointer to that location), which could then break the GC when it tries to walk the object graph.

Right, though if I create and use the span entirely from within instance methods of the struct, then I should be assured that the struct is still alive (hence why I made UnsafeValues private).

@zstewart yep, but I wonder whether a switch expression would be easier, i.e. => index switch { 0 => field0, ... 7 => field7, _ => SomeCheekyThrowMethod(); }
